# CRM 2011 OData substringof Wildcards?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, odata, crm

I cannot find any reference in the oData specification or CRM documentation but it seems that CRM (if not oData itself) supports some form of wildcards when using the substringof filter in an oData query.

For example using the following data:

```
[{
 FullName: "Jim Glynn",
 EMailAddress1: "someone_j@example.com"
},
{
 FullName: "Nancy Anderson",
 EMailAddress1: "someone_c@example.com"
},
{
 FullName: "Maria Campbell",
 EMailAddress1: "someone_d@example.com"
}]
```

The following oData query will return all 3 records whereas I would expect to only get the 2nd one:

```
OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$select=FullName,EMailAddress1&$filter=substringof('_c',EMailAddress1)
```

However adding a '@' to the string value will correctly return only the 2nd record:

```
OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$select=FullName,EMailAddress1&$filter=substringof('_c@',EMailAddress1)
```

We have pored over the oData documentation as well as the MS docs and cannot find any reference to wildcard support at all. But the only explanation we can think of is that the underscore is being used as a wildcard. If that is true it would be nice to know how to escape it to properly execute a search on '_c' as in our first query string above.

Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 2):

OK we figured it out - it's a performing a SQL query so it's using the SQL wildcards in there. It would be nice if there was any mention of this in the oData or MS documentation but hopefully somebody else will find this useful.

Comment: Especially since this isn't part of the OData standard:
http://services.odata.org/AdventureWorksV3/AdventureWorks.svc/ProductCatalog()?$filter=substringof('a',Description)&$select=Description
vs http://services.odata.org/AdventureWorksV3/AdventureWorks.svc/ProductCatalog()?$filter=substringof('_a',Description)&$select=Description

Comment: I would not rely on this as I would consider this a bug. Someone did not do proper SQL escaping...